# Need to extract 8 & 9 digit file numbers from 40,000 emails using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, vbscript, extract

I am attempting to extract 8 & 9 digit file numbers from 40,000 emails that have been saved as .txt files.  The File numbers can appear any where in the email(s)...(it's not a standard form), but should always be 8 or 9 digits in length.  The file numbers can also be formatted several different ways Like: xxx xx xxxx, xxx-xx-xxxx, xxxxxxxxx, 8 digit #'s: YY YYY YYY, YY-YYY-YYY, YYYYYYYY.  I created a PowerShell script that reads the text file extracts the file numbers matching the said pattern and creates & saves them to a .csv file.

Problems: If there is any text proceeding the file# on the line, the script fails to grab the file #.  It also grabs additional text (on the same line after the File #).  I need only exact matches to the set patterns.

Solution does not need to be in PowerShell, If there is a better solution in vbscript I'm also open to that.

current script is below:

```
$Num = @()

$Num += Select-String -Path "$PSSCRIPTROOT\text.txt" -Pattern '\d{8}$|^\d{2}\s\d{3}\s\d{3}$|^\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{3}$'


$Num += Select-String -Path "$PSSCRIPTROOT\text.txt" -Pattern '\d{9}$|^\d{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{4}$|^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$'


ForEach ($Matches in $Num){


$Found = $Matches.ToString().Split(":")
$o = new-object PSObject
$o | add-member NoteProperty "FoundOnLine" $Found[2]
$o | add-member NoteProperty "Number" $Found[3]


$o | export-csv "$PSscriptroot\FoundNumbers.csv" -notypeinformation -Append 
Write-Output $o
```

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick actually ...

```
$File = "$PSSCRIPTROOT\text.txt"
$Pattern = '\d\d(\s|-)*\d(\s|-)*\d(\s|-)*\d{4,5}'

Select-String -Path $File -Pattern $Pattern -AllMatches | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
```